# The closest-to puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geography

**What's the answer hidden in the puzzle below?**

---

[image: puzzle image showing maps and polygons]

From left to right:

```
   (-) - - (-) - - - - (-) - - - - (-) - (-) - - (-) - - - (-) (-) - - - - (-) - -
   11       6          2,9          7     5       1         8   3          4,10
```

---

***Note: Although one doesn't really fit in this category (the answer to this puzzle), I still decided to include it. It doesn't affect the puzzle at all, just a technical matter. Good luck!***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The puzzle asks us to look for ...

> ... countries whose shapes resemble the given geometric shapes as closely as possible in the given continents – it's a "closest-to" puzzle.

So:

> Most circular country in Africa: **SIERRA LEONE**
>  Squarest country in Africa: **EGYPT**
>  Triangular country in Central America: **NICARAGUA**
>  Hexagonal country in Europe: **FRANCE**
>
>  (France is sometimes referred to as the Hexagon, so that made me think of the similarity of the shapes. From just looking at a map of Africa, I considered Sierra Leone, Lesotho and Eswatini as circles and the mainland of Equatorial Guinea as a rectangle, but an internet search brought up [this article](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/sierra-leone-is-the-worlds-roundest-country-and-egypt-the-squarest-one/), whose answers neatly fit the number of blanks in the puzzle.)

The overall answer is:

> "**COUNTRY-GONS**", that is country shapes that are nearly regular polygons. You get it if you write the four coutries above in the given pattern and extract the numberes letters:
>
> ```
> (S) I E (R) R A L E (O) N E E G (Y) P (T) N I (C) A R A (G) (U) A F R A (N) C E
> 11       6          2,9          7     5       1         8   3          4,10
> ```

Comment: Lovely job. Great article to link to for info too. I was so focussed on using the number of sides of the shapes to extract the nth letter of the various continents... I suspect I was not the only one!

Comment: Thanks. Hehe, Prim3numbah is very good at sending one down various rabbit holes with some casual sketches, no?

Comment: I thought the dotted lines were equator or tropic of cancer and we were to find countries in those continents "closest to" that lol :D Very Smart work @MOehm like always and I agree ^

Comment: I suspected it wouldn't be easy to figure out what it was all about, but hoped that L'Hexagone would give it away - which it did in this case. I didn't want to give away too much in the title either. Great job!